# Is there a way to create categories within entities in LUIS.ai?

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

I am learning LUIS.ai and I would like to know if there is a way to "categorize" entities so I don't have to code that logic in my client.

Example: Let's say that my domain is movies and I have a entity "Genre". So I can ask for "romantic movies" or "war movies". That is relatively easy, but if I type "love movies" or "rom-com movies", then I have to code the logic to find the equivalences (love = romantic and many more equivalences like that).

[image]

Is there a way to create "categories" within an entity? So the entity Genre could have "romantic", with list of synonyms, then "war" with other synonyms and so on. This way I wouldn't need to do the checking in my client (if(genre == "romantic" || genre == "love" || ...) return Genres.Romantic;).

Comment: I think a list entity would be the best fit for what you want, you create an entity where a word has a list of synonyms to it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-entity-types#list-entity

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Maged Refaat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14095716/maged-refaat). Posting your comment section response to Answer section as it would help other community users.

> [list
> entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-entity-types#list-entity)
> would be the best fit for what you want, you can create an entity
> where a word has a list of synonyms to it.